# React-native version conflict

Tags: react-native, npm-install, native-base

Previously i have used `react-native 0.38`. I have changed the version to `react-native 0.40` and run `npm install`. The app is build successfully, but in the login page native-base input component is not visible.

I have cleaned and rebuild the project but it is not working. If i degrade it to `react-native 0.38`, it works properly. My native-base version is `native-base 2.0.9`.

Comment: Is there any error message, or just not visible?

Comment: just the native-base input field is not visible

Comment: Check if the input component has changed with the versions

Comment: The input component i have used is from native-base 2.0.9.  I didn't change the native-base version.

Comment: In that case, share your source code for the screen